# Specifying the root of the ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my xaml code (simplified)

```
<Canvas Name="c1">
   <misc controls Canvas.ZIndex="1">
   <Canvas Name="c2">
      <Button Canvas.ZIndex="2" Name="b1" />
      <misc>
   </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

I wish that the button is placed above the misc controls in Canvas c1. So I use the Canvas.ZIndex property. But it is relative to Canvas c2 and I would like it to be relative to Canvas c1.
How could I do that ? Is there a way to specify the root canvas of the zindex property ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button on Canvas 2 knows nothing about Canvas 1. Set the z index of Canvas 2 as a whole instead.

```
<Canvas Name="c1">
   <misc controls Canvas.ZIndex="1">
   <Canvas ZIndex="2" Name="c2">
      <Button Name="b1" />
      <misc>
   </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

(Or simply re-order your tags)